# Importing from one running script into another

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a python file named `mainbot.py` which has the following code:

```
import time

x = [1,2,3,4] # Existing list

for i in range (5,5000):
    x.append(i)
    time.sleep(5)
    print (x)
```

its simple and its just adding in an existing list, one number..

Now I want to import this list , **while it's runnng**, from another file lets say `monitor.py`. To be able to see what is the current list .

So I've tried to write the following code to the new file but its won't work...

```
from mainbot import x

print (x)
```

Am I close or python just won't do it?

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think it's python

Comment: @u12 what makes you think that?

Comment: As you write _while it is running_ importing the variable in order to access, change or read it from both scripts that could most definitely result in a threading or multiprocessing related issue. If you run your scripts independently from each other (as standalone processes), sharing information between these processes/programs would require some inter-process-communications (like shared memory, IPC routines ...). In contrast, running the code as threads from within the same process would require thread-safe data types to prevent access violations and ensure consistent data.

Comment: @Greg . I've thought about it but if i try and import from mainbot only it says x not defined. and its running the mainbot from the start... What i need is when for example the list has reached  "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" to run the monitor.py and see that specific moment what is the list containing..

Comment: you need to use mainbot.x then. Still not sure what would happen.

Comment: @albert so in simple English its a dead end ?

Comment: @ΧρήστοςΓεωργίου: Definitely not a dead end, but not as easy as importing a variable from another script as they are executed independently. If you can reach your implementation goal with threading, I would suggest encapsulating `monitor.py` in a function an run this as a thread. You could then use a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to share data between these threads.

Comment: @ albert Is there any way to make the first file running on the background and monitor its results somehow from inside python from the second one ?

Comment: @ΧρήστοςΓεωργίου: That is possible by applying multiprocessing techniques. However, I try to avoid this whenever possible: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @albert that threading is the way to do this. You could use a `threading.Timer` to periodically peek at the list.

Comment: Buddy can you try your code in IDLE 3.9.2  i can see it running , like after every second i can observer the list incrementing  the code is right

Answer (score 0):

Buddy not sure but your code is working fine ,

i can see the list incrementing in real-time when i run monitor.py

just make sure you kept both files in same directory or just import the path first if its an different directory and run you script

Please see my screenshot below [image]